# Creating a Yii application setup / installation page

Tags: php, yii

I am creating an application and will be deployed to production soon.

For the ease of convenience, I would like to create a custom setup and installation page which will allow users to input variable values to be used in config/main.php as well as to execute the RBAC setup and create necessary tables.

For most web application, there is an 'install' folder which users point their browsers to and begin the app installation. How do I implement something similar in Yii?

Comment: What you are saying I have not seen. Let's take Wordpress as example. You paste the WP code in a public directory and then you use a form to config your app.

Comment: Which is precisely what he is looking for (simplified). I guess you could setup your SiteController to forward to a custom action (i.e. installAction) if no database is detected? You could use this action to link to all necessary resource, run any commands you may need, etc? Not entirely sure but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 1):

I think a great start were the [app manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/app-manager/) extension which provides much of what you need. It doesn't do anything with the RBAC setup, though. Perhaps you want the [auth extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth/) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yii does not have an installation folder, you just download and extract it and put in your server like Wamp/Xampp or etc. and then you can install a new Yii application through command prompt.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16> "c:\wamp\www\yii\framework\yiic.bat" webapp "c:\wamp\
www\newyii"
```

When you run above command, then you will see the following command.

Create a web application under 'c:\wamp\www\newyii'?  [no]:

You write Y. and then create your new application.

For more understanding. you should follow the below link.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think you have misread my question. I want to create a installation folder that will perform installation of my app. Not creating an app from scratch using the console.